# Is it possible to use a wordpress page into a Nuxt project?

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm going to make a landing page with Wordpress, but I have to use this landing page into a Nuxt.js project. Is it possible?

Comment: Why both of them and not only one? Why do you **have** to use it into a Nuxt project?

Comment: Also, which part of Wordpress are you using for this? Can't you make the integration with regular HTML + CSS into the Nuxt project?

Comment: It's because the landing page will be develop by other person in wordpress. And in my project I use NuxtJs. Only I have to use this landing page in the initial page of my proyect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could somehow try to load the whole thing (with an iframe or even something more dirty like nesting the Nuxt project into Wordpress), this is probably a bad idea.
Mainly because the front page will be done with a specific set of tools, like Bootstrap, some jQuery plugins (surely Wordpress plugins too).

Nonetheless, on top of the complexity of the task, you will probably have a tremendous amount of performance hit. Having that on the initial page load is probably the worst you can do to a website **then** you will have to load the whole Nuxt app on top of it. All the users will be long gone already.

So, I suggest speaking with the person there and ask them to work with Vanilla HTML + CSS (or the any other tools similar to yours). Then, you could maybe refactor some parts thanks to Vue (with `v-for` for example).
But for maintenance, performance and use of use: you should not mix 2 totally different server side rendering tools.

Otherwise, if the communication is hard you can always replicate the whole thing thanks to some code source inspection. For a single page, this should be totally doable.